# In R, carry dimension names into a matrix product

Tags: r, matrix

I have two matrices `A` and `B` with dimension names, but not row or column names.  I want to multiply them and carry over the dimension names.  Specifically, I would like to multiply the transpose of `A` (an m by n matrix with the row dimension called "Variables" and the column dimension called "students") by `B` (an m by q matrix with the row dimension called "Coefficients" and the column dimension called "models") to get `C` (an n by q matrix with the row dimension called "Students" and the column dimension called "Models").  The code below produces the correct matrix, but without the dimension names.

```
A = matrix(data = c(1:5, 10*(1:5)), nrow = 2, dimnames = list("Variables" = NULL, "students" = NULL))
B = matrix(data=c(1:6), nrow = 2, dimnames = list("Coefficients" = NULL, "models" = NULL))
A
B
dim(A)
dim(B)
dimnames(A)
dimnames(B)
C = crossprod(A,B)
C
dim(C)
dimnames(C)
```

I'd like the output (of running just the variable `C`) to look like the following:

```
        Models
students [,1] [,2] [,3]
    [1,]    5   11   17
    [2,]   11   25   39
    [3,]   25   55   85
    [4,]   80  180  280
    [5,]  140  320  500
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output?  The two matrices have different dimnames.  It would be better to know what you expect.

Comment: Actually you are multiplying transposed `A` over `B`, compare to `t(A) %*% B`

Comment: akrun - Good point.  I added the expected output.  David Arenburg - Good point.  I fixed it in the question.

Comment: possible one liner `\`dimnames<-\`(t(A) %*% B, setNames(list(NULL, NULL), c(names(dimnames(A))[2], names(dimnames(B))[2])))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you could do this with `crossprod` directly but I wrapped a small piece of code around it that seems to work:

```
crossprod2 <- function(x, y){
  row <- names(dimnames(x))[2] #save row name
  col <- names(dimnames(y))[2] #save col name
  cp <- crossprod(x,y)         #run crossprod
  dimnames(cp) <- list(NULL,NULL)   #create dimnames
  names(dimnames(cp)) <- c(row,col) #set the correct names
  cp 
 }
```

Alternatively, as per @PauldeBarros 's comment you can also do:

```
crossprod2 <- function(x, y){ row <- dimnames(x)[2] #save row names 
                              col <- dimnames(y)[2] #save col names 
                              dn = list(row[[1]], col[[1]]) 
                              names(dn) = list(names(row), names(col)) 
                              cp <- crossprod(x,y) #run crossprod 
                              dimnames(cp) <- dn #apply dimnames cp 
                              cp
}
```

In which case any row names or column names will be preserved if they exist.

Output:

```
> crossprod2(A,B)
        models
students [,1] [,2] [,3]
    [1,]    5   11   17
    [2,]   11   25   39
    [3,]   25   55   85
    [4,]   80  180  280
    [5,]  140  320  500
```

Comment: This is great, but loses the rownames and colnames (if they exist).  Interestingly, crossprod keeps those AND the dimension names as long as there are rownames and colnames.  For something general, what about `crossprod2 <- function(x, y){
  row <- dimnames(x)[2] #save row names
  col <- dimnames(y)[2] #save col names
  dn = list(row[[1]], col[[1]])  
  names(dn) = list(names(row), names(col))
  cp <- crossprod(x,y)         #run crossprod
  dimnames(cp) <- dn   #apply dimnames
  cp 
}`

Comment: @PauldeBarros Yeah your suggested way works great. Obviously, you are posting the question so you have in mind a lot more things than myself. I only try to address the problem with the available information I have.I will add the alternative here for reference for people having the same problem.